# Looking for CSS-lint-type tool that will catch useless CSS like td{margin:15px}

Tags: css

I just spent a fair bit of time debugging some CSS.  It turns out that the problem was that this CSS was using useless directives such as

```
td{margin:15px;}
```

What sends me for a loop is that every CSS-checking/validation tool I tried on that code was completely silent about.  None gave even a mild heads-up along the lines of "BTW, that `td{margin:15px;}` is doing zilch for you...".

Does anyone know of a CSS tool that would alert one of such useless CSS?

In the past I have used code validation tools that would, for example, alert the user that the last line of the following function is never executed, and therefore, it is as useless as the `td{margin:15px}` above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  return 0;
  printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

I'm looking for something in the same spirit, but for CSS.

Comment: TD doesn't take margin? Or why is it useless? Do you mean it just isn't *applied* here? What if later someone adds `* { margin: 200px; }`? Yes, these questions all have a point - I suspect the question is about finding *applied* overlaps/redundancies.

Comment: Also, sometimes the CSS properties that seem to be completely unused and redundant, may in fact be "fixes" for some browser bugs. For example, `display:inline` for floated elements (which, in theory, should be ignored) was widely used at some point against IE6 "double margin" bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not find a **"CSS Linter"** that will tell you a `margin` on a `td` is useless because if it did it would be wrong.

It's not useless, it's only useless if the `td` has a `display` of `table-cell` otherwise it will work as normal.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3yNhs/2**

So yeah. a good "linter" would be **http://csslint.net/**, But he won't tell you that it's useless.

That's almost like saying you wan't a linter that will tell you that `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;` is useless, when in fact it is not, because that could be applied in a `:hover` declaration or whatever...

You are the best person to judge and clean your code out.

Comment: It's not impossible to write a linter for this sort of case; it just means it would have to be a “whole-stylesheet” linter that considers all the rules in effect (under some notion of _normal circumstances_).

Comment: Nothings impossible. I doubt you will find one though.

Comment: In effect, a linter would need to actually interpret all of the CSS code, and naturally also parse the HTML or XML document it is applied to, and here consider, among other things, the “Applies to” restrictions in the descriptions of properties in CSS specifications. So it would be more or less like a browser. Unfortunately, the developer tools in browsers don’t seem to help with issues like this. They show the computed value of a property, without telling that it does not apply (i.e. it has no effect).